# GitHub Gist API Gives 422 Error, unsure why

Tags: swift, github, gist

I'm using the Github API to store json documents as Gists. Following the API as best I can, I get a 422 error. This indicates that there's nothing wrong with the request, but it's not being processed. Hints elsewhere indicate that this can be because of server-side specific processing rules, but I don't know what they would be.

A sample of the JSON I'm sending as the request is here: https://gist.github.com/urbanistica/fa2cab822cc7ce6a40f6b9394f811075

My Auth token is up to date, and I don't think that can have anything to do with it, since I would not be getting this error. The Github API docs for creating a Gist are here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/gists/gists#create-a-gist, and from what I can determine, the JSON I'm sending agrees with this. The JSON has been checked for validity on JSONLint and in ThunderClient. The headers are set as recommended. I'm nowhere near the rate limiter, and I don't have other information that seems relevant to why this doesn't work....

This is the code:

```
struct GistPayload : Codable {
    var Public : Bool
    var description : String
    var files : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, ProjectExport>>
}

@objc func exportProject() {
    guard let projectExport = userProject?.export() else { return }
    let src = GistPayload(Public: true, description: "testing Gist upload", files: ["testGist" : ["content" : projectExport]])
    sendToGist(payload: src)
}

func encode(src : GistPayload) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(src)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {print("problem \(error)")}
   return nil
}

func sendToGist(payload : GistPayload) {
    guard var data = encode(src: payload) else {
        print("no data")
        return
    }
    data = data.replacingOccurrences(of: "Public", with: "public")
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/gists")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/vnd.github+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(StartController.token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil
        else {                                                               
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        do {
            print("done")
        } catch {
            print(error) // parsing error
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            } else {
                print("unable to parse response as string")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The Docs say that 422 indicates, "*Validation failed, or the endpoint has been spammed*." I'm me, and I don't abuse Github, if this indicates the problem, how is this flag raised, and how can I avoid it?

EDIT: Using Thunderclient, I can create the gists via the API. I'm using JSON sent to the server, so the JSON conforms.

I've updated the code to this:

```
struct GistData {
    var filename : String
    var description : String
    var publc : Bool
    var payload : ProjectExport
    
    func files() ->   Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, ProjectExport>> {
        var rslt : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, ProjectExport>>
        return [filename : ["content" : payload]]
    }
    
    func output() -> Output {
        return Output(description: description, Public: publc, files: files())
    }
    
    struct Output : Codable {
        var description : String
        var Public : Bool
        var files : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, ProjectExport>>
    }
}

@objc func exportProject() {
    guard let projectExport = userProject?.export() else { return }
    var gistData = GistData(filename: "newThingie.json", description: "a thing", publc: true, payload: projectExport)
    sendToGist(payload: gistData.output())
}

func encode(src : GistData.Output) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(src)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {print("problem \(error)")}
   return nil
}
```

and this is (still) the response:

```
statusCode should be 2xx, but is 422
```

response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600001d48d40> { URL: https://api.github.com/gists } { Status Code: 422, Headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
"*"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
38981
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
"Tue, 22 Nov 2022 04:10:48 GMT"
);
Server =     (
"GitHub.com"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
"max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload"
);
Vary =     (
"Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With"
);
"access-control-expose-headers" =     (
"ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset"
);
"content-security-policy" =     (
"default-src 'none'"
);
"github-authentication-token-expiration" =     (
"2023-02-20 03:06:05 UTC"
);
"referrer-policy" =     (
"origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"x-accepted-oauth-scopes" =     (
""
);
"x-content-type-options" =     (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" =     (
deny
);
"x-github-media-type" =     (
"github.v3; format=json"
);
"x-github-request-id" =     (
"D032:5EB9:94899C:9949C2:637C4BC8"
);
"x-oauth-scopes" =     (
gist
);
"x-ratelimit-limit" =     (
5000
);
"x-ratelimit-remaining" =     (
4992
);
"x-ratelimit-reset" =     (
1669090408
);
"x-ratelimit-resource" =     (
core
);
"x-ratelimit-used" =     (
8
);
"x-xss-protection" =     (
0
);
} }

EDIT AND SOLUTION: I'm including the working code here:

```
  struct Tester : Codable {
    var description : String
    var publc : Bool
    var filename : String
    var payload : String
    
    func encodePayload() {
        
    }
    func files() -> Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> {
        return [filename : ["content" : payload]]
    }
    
    func output() -> Output {
        return Output(description: description, Public: publc, files: files())
    }
                
    struct Output : Codable {
        var description : String
        var Public : Bool
        var files :  Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>
    }
}



@objc func exportProject() {
    guard let projectExport = userProject?.export() else { return }
    guard var encodedData = encode(src: projectExport) else {
        print("problem encoding data")
        return
    }
    var gistTest = Tester(description: "please work", publc: true, filename: "justMaybe.md", payload: encodedData)
    sendToGist(payload: gistTest.output())
}

func encode(src : ProjectExport) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(src)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {print("problem \(error)")}
   return nil
}

func encode(src : Tester.Output) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(src)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {print("problem \(error)")}
   return nil
}

func sendToGist(payload : Tester.Output) {
    guard var data = encode(src: payload) else {
        print("no data")
        return
    }
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/gists")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpBody = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/vnd.github+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(StartController.token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
   

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil
        else {                                                               // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        do {
            print("done")
        } catch {
            print(error) // parsing error
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            } else {
                print("unable to parse response as string")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: `422: Validation failed, or the endpoint has been spammed.`. Ratelimit is don't react, so check you post body.

Comment: Hey @HenryTrần: yes, but I've validated the JSON, and it doesn't seem to be wrong in any way I can see. The API is simple enough, so I don't think it's the JSON. So they think it's spam, I guess?

Comment: post body is `application/json`. replace `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by `application/json` and retry.

Comment: @HenryTrần : actually, that's just an artifact of trying both. But changing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: ""Content-Length" = ( 38981 );" There is content in the response. Print it (coverted to String) and it might tell you more...

Comment: I think that's just the content sent?

Comment: Since it's in the URLResponse, does the API returns really the sent data (why?) or does it return an useful info? Would you mind check it? It could send back to you "invalid vallue for field XxX", "missing value for field XxX", etc... I'm not familiar with GitHub API, but some API might return this kind of informations... So print `responseString` even if it's a 422?

Comment: Hi @Larme : I found a solution, and now the error is gone, so… I'm posting the working but rough code up in the original question now... I think it can be improved, but the main thing was that I seemed to have to encode the payload data into an encoded string, include that as a property of a struct, and then encode the struct. Trying to encode everything all at one go seemed to do something bad, which I will bet comes down to string quotation levels....

Comment: After your working edit: What does this return `userProject?.export()`?

Comment: @JohnHanley : Hey John, that's basically a struct containing all the data. It's checked out fine. The basic purpose of this is to move the data generated by a user using the app to point where others also using the app can load it into their version :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5Tfd90xCeQ&t=2s

Comment: Your code works. Post an example as the answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley: there's a second part of this, where I decode the text coming back from Github. Once I'm sure the out and back cycle doesn't introduce any changes, I will.